# Performing ϵ-closure on NFA

Tags: computational-mathematics

Say you have an NFA where the only transitions from the start state are $\epsilon$, when performing an $\epsilon$-closure then you have a state that is completely isolated and I'm not sure if my understanding is correct, because the result doesn't make sense to me.
As an example:

|  | a | b | c | ε |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -> A |  |  |  | BC * |
| B | B | B |  | * |
| C | C |  | C | * |

Where the $\epsilon$-closure table is:

|  | $\epsilon$-closure |
| --- | --- |
| -> A | ABC * |
| B | B * |
| C | C * |

My understanding then is that after performing an $\epsilon$-closure, we get this NFA

|  | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -> A |  |  | * |
| B | B | B | * |
| C | C |  | C * |